# Reading many camera streams (16, 32, 64) with C++ and OpenCV

Tags: opencv, video, video-capture

I'm trying to do some research for a new application which is surveillance-based and has to be able to handle the output for up to 64 different cameras. While I don't think the end result should be to view them all at the same time (that'd be nice), the goal would be to record the data/video feed from all cameras to whatever directory, and either stream from 4-8 or so at a time, or read the video files and do the same, to be able to see them "live".

Does anyone have any knowledge into this space? Any advice on whether I should stick with OpenCV to do this? I have read that OpenCV gets a little cranky after 2 camera feeds. I could run the OpenCV processing in parallel for the currently shown 4-8 cameras or something, maybe. Will I be forced to use lower-level libraries like ffmpeg to do the video communication more directly?

With more than 4 cameras or so, most people will be using external video capture or DVR card. With 64, a 64 Port PoE switch. Does anyone have experience with this space? Can I get these outputs through to OpenCV, or at that point maybe it doesn't matter if OpenCV is reading from a file stream instead of the cameras directly? I'm thinking I could at least have OpenCV working on 2 cameras at a time, so you could live view 1 or 2. If I want to incorporate motion detection onto all 64 cameras, I'd have to post-process the video feeds/files into parallel threads running OpenCV algorithms, I'm just guessing...

Any advice into this space would be helpful!

Comment: The [tag:c++] tag is reserved for questions about specific c++ code. May be your question is better asked at SE Software Recommendations.

Comment: I can use opencv with 3 cameras (USB buswindows 10 opencv 3.1 VS2013) . Where do you read "I have read that OpenCV gets a little cranky after 2 camera feeds"?